# Remove both duplicates row

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-dataset

Good day colleagues.
I have a big dataset (about 237 000 000 rows).
There are a lot of columns.
For example, I need to delete all duplicates with column names `userId`, `VTS`.

```
userId Vts moreColumn1 moreColumn2
10     150     2           3              -delete
11     160     1           6
10     150     0           1              -delete
```

I am bad with SQL. Have tried different variant from Internet, but it doesn't work.

**UPDATE:**

Ty for answers! I forgot to say i use java.
There is my optimized code for java:

```
viewingDataset.groupBy("userId", "VTS")
                .count()
                .where("count = 1")
                .drop("count")
                .join(viewingDataset, JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(asList("userId", "VTS")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can aggregate with count, filter the result and join back

```
df.groupBy("userId", "Vts").count
  .where($"count" === 1)
  .drop("count")
  .join(df, Seq("userId", "Vts"))
```

It is possible to get the same result with window functions, but it less robust if data is skewed and on average much more expensive.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth If you need a definitive proof it is easy to check at scale with synthetic data with different cardinality and average group size. If explanation is enough - in the worst case scenario you will shuffle a single value par group on top of what window function does.  In the best case scenario you shuffle at most one value / per  group / per partition and broadcast the result - the smaller cardinality of grouping and the higher number of duplicates the more you gain from join.

Comment: Compared to that window functions will always take worst case path where all records are shuffled.  The code in the answer can be improved even more, depending on a prior knowledge. Overall this Spark 102 with the same rationale as avoid-group-by-key.

Comment: ok I was not aware that window-function will actually shuffle the records, I thought only the partial aggregates will be shuffled..

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Yeah, there are no partial aggregates in window functions. To make it worse some unbounded frame variants have (if nothing changed) really ugly complexity.

Comment: @user8371915 Ty for answer. I forgot to say i use java, but i have found a way to use this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want with Window functions:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window._

ds.withColumn("aux", count("*")
.over(Window.partitionBy($"userId", $"VTS")))
.where($"aux"===1)
.drop($"aux")
```

partitionBy will count how many elements are by partition according to the columns you are sending as paremeters (userId and VTS in your example). 
Then with the `where` clause we'll keep only the rows from partitions where the count is 1, i.e. the unique rows.

**Result of the partitionBY clause**

```
ds.withColumn("aux", count("*").over(Window.partitionBy($"userId", $"VTS"))).show

+-------+----+------------+------------+---+
| userId| VTS| moreColumn1| moreColumn2|aux|
+-------+----+------------+------------+---+
|     10| 150|           2|           3|  2|
|     10| 150|           0|           1|  2|
|     11| 160|           1|           6|  1|
+-------+----+------------+------------+---+
```

**Final Result**

```
+-------+----+------------+------------+
| userId| VTS| moreColumn1| moreColumn2|
+-------+----+------------+------------+
|     11| 160|           1|           6|
+-------+----+------------+------------+
```